# Android ImageView Select Mark

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

There are 10 images in my application. User has to choose one of them. I want it to be tick mark in the upper right corner of the clicked image and not in others. How can I do that?

Comment: Share the code that you have tried

Comment: I thought of checking one by one. and that sounds ridiculous. So I haven't tried anything :(

Comment: Please search on your browser you can definitely get solution from there. You just think, find, and try to implement and if get any issue then post your question here.

Comment: I asked because I couldn't find any answer. @Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your images in a recyclerview and maintain selected image's state with the following adapter

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private int selectedPos = -1;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setSelectedPos(int pos) {
        selectedPos = pos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position == selectedPos) {
            holder.ivCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.ivCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView ivCheck;
        private ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_src);
            ivCheck = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_check);

            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    setSelectedPos(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_src"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_check"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_tick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use FrameLayout and ImageView and manage selected state for each image. If image is selected then make imgCheck visible otherwise hide it.

```
<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_checked"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope it will help!!